# Show that orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that all orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable over $C$. I know that a matrix is orthogonal if $Q^TQ = QQ^T = I$ and $Q^T = Q^{-1}$, and that a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. How can I start this proof?

Comment: Maybe, in the first row, you meant to write "all orthogonal m. are diagonalizable ..." ?

Comment: I don't understand how that's different from what I've already written...?

Comment: In first line (not title) I read "..all diagonalizable m. are diagonalizable .."

Comment: ^I edited it to fix that. To the OP, do you know how to prove that a normal matrix is diagonalizable? If so, orthogonal matrices are normal, which would finish the proof.

Comment: Ack, sorry, it's early and I missed that. And @NicholasStull I do know it to some degree but I would still appreciate seeing it written out.

Comment: Another thing I could tell you as a hint: Spectral Theorem. If no one has said more about it by the time I get back in a bit over 2 hours, I'll type it out.

Comment: @NicholasStull I do know of Spectral Theorem but am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: @NicholasStull The statements of the spectral theorem I've seen use $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$ for the definition of normal. This is not equivalent to $AA^T=A^TA$ for complex matrices. Is there an alternate version of the spectral theorem / normality that applies to this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As people have indicated, you could simply apply the spectral theorem. Here I run through a specialized argument to the orthogonal case:

Since $Q$ is orthogonal we have $\langle Qv, Qw \rangle = (Qv)^*Qw = v^* Q^T Q w = \langle v, w \rangle$.

Given any eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, if we have some vector $w$ orthogonal to $v$ then we have $\lambda \langle v, Qw \rangle = \langle Qv, Qw \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle = 0$, so $Q$ maps $v^\perp$ into itself. We can induct on the dimension of our space to show $Q$ acts diagonalizably on $v^\perp$ so it acts diagonalizably on $v \oplus v^\perp$

We can infact say more:

Note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvector of $Q$ then we have $|\lambda|\|v\| = \langle \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle = \langle Qv, Qv \rangle = \|v\|$. We conclude all the eigenvalues have norm $1$.

If $v,w$ are eigenvectors with different eigenvalues then we have $\langle v, w \rangle = \langle Qv, Qw \rangle = \langle \lambda v, \mu w \rangle = \lambda \mu^* \langle v, w \rangle$. Thus if $\lambda \mu^* \neq 1$ then $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal.

Combining these one can show that $Q = PRP^{-1}$ where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $R$ is a block diagonal matrix with $1,-1$ and $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices down the diagonal.

Comment: What do you mean by "$Q$ acts diagonalizably on $v^\perp$ and on $v\oplus v^\perp$"?

Comment: Since Q maps $v^\perp$ to itself we get an induced linear map, $Q|_{v^\perp}: v^\perp \to v^\perp$. It's easy to see that this map is orthogonal and on a vector space of one less dimension, so by induction this map is diagonalizable.

Comment: @NickR, There are some missing squared root, unless you change $||v||$ to $||v||^2$

Comment: If you're using $\langle-,-\rangle$ for a complex inner product (conjugate-linear in first argument), it is not true that $\langle Qv,Qw\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$, which makes the whole answer wrong.

Comment: @coiso Let’s assume that $Q$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries and that $Q^T Q = I$. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb C^n$. If $v, w \in \mathbb C^n$ then $\langle Qv, Qw \rangle = (Qv)^* Qw = v^* Q^* Q w = v^* Q^T Q w = v^* w = \langle v, w \rangle$. I used the fact that $Q^*$, the conjugate transpose of $Q$, is equal to $Q^T$ (because $Q$ has real entries by assumption).

Comment: @littleO I was under the impression $Q$ was complex orthogonal. That's how I came to this question when searching, and OP mentioned "over C." But OP didn't specify complex orthogonal and real orthogonal is the usual interpretation of "orthogonal," plus OP accepted this answer, so I guess real orthogonal was the intended meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $Q$ is orthogonal then $Q$ is normal, because
\begin{equation*}
Q Q^T = Q^T Q = I.
\end{equation*}
So the spectral theorem implies that $Q$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: The statements of the spectral theorem I've seen use $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$ for the definition of normal. This is not equivalent to $AA^T=A^TA$ for complex matrices. Is there an alternate version of the spectral theorem / normality that applies to this situation?