# first projection does not have a continuous section

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $R=\{(X,Y)\in \Bbb R^3\times \Bbb R^3: |X|=|Y|=1, \langle X,Y \rangle=0\}$.

Knowing that $R$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^2 \times \Bbb S^1$, prove that $R$'s projection onto first coordinate $Pr_1 : (X, Y ) \mapsto X $ doesn't have a continuous section, i.e. a continuous map $s:\Bbb S^2 \to R$ such that $Pr_1\circ s=Id_{\Bbb S^2}$.

Thank you for your help and comments.

What I tried so far:

I tried to use algebra to find a contradiction:
If a continuous section exists, I tried to prove that $\Bbb S^1$ is an extension of $\Bbb S2$ through an exact sequence: $\Bbb S^1 \to R \to \Bbb S^2$ which will imply that $R \cong \Bbb S^2 \rtimes \Bbb S^1$.
Hoping to go further and prove that the semi-direct product is direct and that we have a homeomorphism between $R$ and $\Bbb S^2 \times \Bbb S^1$

Comment: Why are you interested in this problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean $\ldots (X,Y)\in\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\ldots$?

Comment: @James please check my edit on how I am trying to solve it. I am interested in $SO(3, \Bbb R)$ and its topology right now so trying to do some exercices, and this is one of them.

Comment: @Neal yes all vectors are in $\Bbb R^3$

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. 1) $R$ is not correctly defined (see Neal's comment). It seems that $R \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \times  \mathbb{R}^3$. 2) What is the range of $Pr_1$? I guess you mean it is $S^2$, if it were $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $Pr_1$ would not even be surjective.

Comment: Right @PaulFrost sorry for the missing info, I fixed the domain of $R$. and yes $Pr_1$ is R's projection so it is in $\Bbb S^2$

Comment: Then you should write $s : S^2 \to R$.

Comment: Exactly, I edited the question, thank you!

Comment: Am I crazy or would a choice for this section be a nonvanishing unit vector field on $S^2$

Comment: I think so @AndresMejia as the projection on the second coordinate of the section $pr_s: \Bbb S^2 \to \Bbb S^1: X\to Y$ would yield a non vanishing vector field you suggest. is that a problem?

Comment: @PerelMan see the hairy ball theorem

Comment: Right I missed that! it should contradict brouwer's hairy ball.

Comment: @AndresMejia:  I agree that $R$ is simply the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$ so a section would give a non-vanishing section, contradicting the hairy ball theorem.  But the proof idea (not homeo to $S^2\times S^1$ implies no section) has the advantage of showing that *none* of the non-trivial $S^1$-bundles over $S^2$ has a section.  Since the unit tangent bundle is one example of such a bundle, this is, in some sense, a more general result than the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh I am sure, I (admittedly) did not read your answer, it is only what occurred to me. That is a strong justfication to do  the proof properly. Due to my ignorance in real mathematics, I guess one could use the map $\phi:S^2 \times S^1 \to X$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto s(x)y$ where multiplication is complex multiplication, which I guess is a morphism of bundles (and principal at that) so it is an isomorphism (a contradiction.) Thanks for your further illumination! I'm not sure how to prove the nontriviality of this bundle on the other hand, so perhaps I should thin some more.

Comment: @AndresMejia:  I'm not sure why you say you have "ignorance in real mathematics" - the little interaction we've had has always impressed me!  As far as proving non-triviality of the bundle, I'd probably prove $R$ is diffeo to the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$ and then use the hairy ball theorem ;-).

Comment: @JasonDeVito I was mostly being tongue-in-cheek about the anxiety long computations give me. Thank you very much, funny comment, I think that this is how I would go as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's suppose there is a section $s:S^2\rightarrow R$.  Say $s$ has the form $S(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ for functions $f,g:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.  Being a section means $Pr_1\circ f = Id_{S^2}$, which, in turn, means that $f(x) = x$.

For any $x\in S^2$ and $\theta \in S^1$, we let $R_x(\theta)$ denote the rotation by angle $\theta$ counter-clockwise around the vector $x$.  The map $S^2\times S^1\rightarrow SO(3)$ given by $(x,\theta)\mapsto R_x(\theta)$ is continuous (but not injective, since, for example, $(x,0)\mapsto I$ for any $x\in S^2$).

Note that if $(x,y)\in R$, then $(x,R_x(\theta) y)\in R$ because $R_x(\theta)$ is just acting as a rotation in the plane orthogonal to $x$ (where $y$ lives).  Hence, we can construct a continuous map $\phi:S^2\times S^1\rightarrow R$ by $\phi(x,\theta) = (x, R_x(\theta)g(x))$.

I claim that $\phi$ is bijective.  Momentarily believing this, because $S^2\times S^1$ is compact and $R$ is Hausdorff, this will imply $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, giving a contradiction.

So, why is $\phi$ injective?  Well, assume $\phi(x_1, \theta_1) = \phi(x_2,\theta_2),$ that is, assume $(x_1, R_{x_1}(\theta_1)g(x_1)) = (x_2, R_{x_2}(\theta_2)g(x_2)$.  It is then immediate that $x_1 = x_2$.

The equality coming from the second coordinate now looks like $R_{x_1}(\theta_1) g(x_1) = R_{x_1}(\theta_2)g(x_1)$.  Multiplying both sides by the rotation matrix $R_{x_1}(-\theta_2)$, we see that $R_{x_1}(\theta_1 - \theta_2) g(x_1) = g(x_1)$.  In other words, the rotation matrix $R_{x_1}(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$ has a real $1$-eigenvector $g(x_1)$ which is perpendicular to $x_1$ (which is another real eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$).  It now follows that $R_{x_1}(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = Id$, so $\theta_1 = \theta_2$.

Now, why is $\phi$ surjective?  Well, suppose $(x,y)\in R$.  Let $\theta$ denote the angle between $y$ and $g(x)$.  Then $\phi(x,\theta) = (x, R_x(\theta) g(x)) = (x,y)$.

Comment: This proof is probably too complicated for this problem, but maybe some motivation will help.  There is a free $S^1$ action on $R$ given by rotating the second coordinate in the plane which orthogonal to the first coordinate.  This gives $R$ the structure of a principal $S^1$-bundle over $R/S^1 \cong S^2$.  I've essentially just adapted the more general proof that "a principal bundle admits a section iff its trivial" to the case of this specific bundle.

Comment: Thank you! I am  missing something in the part $R_{x_1}(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = Id \Rightarrow R_{x_1}(\theta_1 - \theta_2) = Id$.  Is it because  a rotation matrix in $\Bbb R^3$ has determinant always 1? and having two eigenvalues 1 implies the third eigenvalue is 1?

Comment: Also, are you considering only $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$?

Comment: To your first comment:  Yes, just as you said.  The last eigenvalue is $1$, and orthogonal matrices are always diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$).  To your second question, I guess I was really thinking of $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.  The fact that $R_x(\theta + 2\pi) = R_x(\theta)$ implies that the map $S^2\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow SO(3)$ factors through the projection $S^2\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^2\times S^1$.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think that all (square) matrices are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: No, not all square matrices are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.  For example,  $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $1,1$, so it would have to diagonalize to the identity.  Then we'd have $PAP^{-1} = I$ so $A = P^{-1} I P = I$, a contradiction.  Here's an MSE post on diagonalizability of orthogonal matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737508/show-that-orthogonal-matrices-are-diagonalizable

Comment: Cristal clear! Thank you @Jason