# Non similar to orthogonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a 3-by-3 matrix with determinant 1 which is not similar to an orthogonal matrix.

I know that a matrix is orthogonal if $AA^T=I$ and a matrix $A$ is similar to a matrix $B$ if there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $B=PAP^{-1}$.

But I can't think of any matrix that is not similar to an orthogonal matrix basing from their definitions.
Can you help me? Any hints will also do. Thanks.

Comment: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues; any eigenvalue of an orthognal matrix has modulus $1$.

Comment: So does that mean there doesn't exist such matrix that is not similar to an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: No. But from the above, all you need to do is find a matrix with determinant $1$ that has $1/3$ (e.g.) as an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Take an upper triangular matrix of all $1$'s on the diagonal and above with $0$'s below the diagonal.

Comment: This would be more interesting if a proof of non-similarity were added, even in outline.

Comment: @hardmath The proof is rather simple. If $1$ are on diagonal   then 1's are also eigenvalues and the eigenvalues of a similar matrix. But the only orthogonal matrix with eigenvalues = 1 ( with algebraic multiplicity $ = 3$) is the identity matrix, which is different from the proposed by CF.

Comment: Is it similar to a JCF with the diagonal equal to 1s?

Comment: @Widawensen:  There are various ways to prove non-similarity, such as noting that [orthogonal matrices are normal, and hence diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1738794/3111).  But for the omission of a sketch of the proof of non-similarity I would have upvoted that Answer.