# If an orthogonal matrix $O$ has characteristic polynomial $p=(t-1)^3$ why must it be $I_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I came across this statement in my linear algebra class:

> If $p(t)=(t-1)^3$ for an orthogonal matrix $O$, then the matrix is $I_3$ and $O\in SO(3,\mathbb{R})$.

I know that this gives that the eigenvalues are all equal to $1$, but I am having difficulty understanding why the rest of the statement is true. Here is what I have tried:

- Used the generalized eigenspace decomposition to write $O$ as an upper-triangular matrix,
- Used the property that $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle =\langle O(v_1), O(v_2)\rangle$.

However I am unable to ascertain why this is the case despite repeated attempts. Is there any proof as to why this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [orthogonal matrices are diagonalisable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737508/show-that-orthogonal-matrices-are-diagonalizable), we can write $O = PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $O$, i.e. $D = I_3$. But then $O = P P^{-1} = I_3$.